# How to get the Intellisense information from csc.exe or msbuild.exe?

Tags: c#, msbuild, intellisense, csc

As everyone knows, Visual Studio supports the IntelliSense function. But in this article, what I wonder is the principle of the IntelliSense implementation.

According to what I know, msbuild.exe is used in Visual Studio to build, and msbuild.exe uses the csc.exe to compile. But here I wonder how can the Intellisense function be supported?

I searched the information related to this and I found this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/visual-studio-integration-msbuild?view=vs-2022

According to the above doc (part Design-time IntelliSense), It seems to be that msbuild.exe uses the csc.exe to compile, Also judging from *"Either the Compile target or one of its dependencies must cause the compiler to receive all the necessary parameters for IntelliSense, particularly all references."* I think the Intellisense function is supported from csc.exe. (I think I may be thinking wrong)

If my guess is right, How to get the Intellisense data from csc.exe (or msbuild.exe)? Is there an article related to this?

If I get it completely wrong, Could show me the article about the principle of the Intellisense implementation?

Besides this, Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading.